# UnauthorizedAccessException on WriteAllText c#

Tags: c#, .net, writealltext

Given an existing temp directory (d:\temp), we run the following code

```
[Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\file.txt", " ");
            File.Delete(@"d:\temp\file.txt");
        }
    }
```

After a while in the for loop, we see the exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'd:\temp\file.txt' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding)
at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
```

of course if we change the code adding a Thread.Sleep(10) like:

```
[Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\file.txt", " ");
            File.Delete(@"d:\temp\file.txt");
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

everything is fine, but we don't want to add a sleep to make everything working. Why such a behavior?

Comment: Does exception raised within this method ?

Comment: Tested it on CLR4 x64. No exception here. The 10,000 iterations took 9.96 secs. Which .NET version do you have?

Comment: It is more than likely that the problem is an OS problem, potentially locking the file so it can't be deleted as the OS is still holding the file.

Comment: Just as a guess (based on the error occurring in FileStream.init()), it's possibly an error related to the number of file handles you have open.

Comment: @Neil: but problem "resolution" is to place Sleep AFTER Delete, here should be something else, by me.

Comment: Or may be Test() method called too much times, so by setting up the Sleep() inside it, let's OS to free allocated resources of the same file from the Test() method's previous call.

Comment: Maybe its being processed by a virus scanner and causing the exception

Comment: @ulrichb we are using clr3.5 x32 windows7

Comment: @ulrichb try also with 100,000 iterations. No problem either?

Comment: @Neil Knight does the code work on your platform?

Comment: @Simon Righarts does the code work on your platform?

Comment: @xpuser, do you have more than one instance of that program running in parallel?